# How long will be 5th edition of PMBOK be basis for PMP certification

Tags: pmp, certification, pmbok

As far as I know the PMBBOK 5th edition will be soon be replaced by a new edition. 
When it is expected that the content of the 6th edition is mandatory for PMP certification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switching date will be March 26th 2018

Comment: **PMP** - 26 March 2018; **ACP** - 26 March 2018; **CAMP** - 21 May 2018; **PgPM** - 25 June 2018.

Answer (score 3):

As many PM training portals say, PMBOK® Guide Sixth Edition is going to be released in Q3'17 (Jun-Aug 2017), and PMP Exam update to PMBOK® Guide 6 will happen in Q1 of 2018.

https://www.project-management-prepcast.com/free/pmp-exam/articles/853-pmbok-6-release-date-and-timeline